# returning a memoryStream as a string

Tags: c#

What is wrong with this statement?

```
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memoryStream.Length)
```

I know about the Dispose pattern, have checked out the underlying memoryStream and seen that there is nothing really happening in the dispose. So why shouldn't I allow one of my developers to do this.

The memoryStream becomes out of scope after the return.

The aim is to make the code succinct and not create references that are not required, Hopefully getting the Garbage Collector to kick in soon as.

Its just niggling me, I feel that the memoryStream lets the party down, when compared to what the other streams do and why they implement the IDispose.

Can someone please give me a good reason not to allow the code above. I got a gut feeing about the code not being right but need some back up. :)

****WeNeedAnswers****
:edit please note the code has changed due to Jon Skeets input, but this questions main core is still relevant.

My original and  error prone code was:

```
return new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Why a downvote? +1 to balance the downvote!

Comment: Thank you kind people. Looking at my responses and what people have said, I think I have come to the decision to play with the GC more fairly. If something is marked IDisposable, I should trust the contractual agreement. It hasn't let me down this far so lets all give the GC a big cheer and play fair with it.

Comment: One last comment. On my readings of discovery, the GC will promote the memoryStream to a higher generation just because it requires finalization no matter what. I suppose it expects the memoryStream to be around a long time. Not my most favourite discovery :(

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: Um, are you sure MemoryStream even *has* a finalizer?

Comment: @Jon I really hope not, make my day say it hasn't  :)

Comment: @Jon It has, but I think its all ok, derived from the Objects finalizer :)

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: In that case it hasn't got a finalizer. The one in Object doesn't count, basically.

Comment: @jon yes I know. Glad to have found it to be so thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd use:

```
string text;
memoryStream.Position = 0;
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

as a more general way of doing it - but your code should at least work. If you're aiming not to create more objects than you need, you should use `Encoding.ASCII` instead of creating a new instance. If you're *really* paranoid about copying, you could use:

```
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(),
                                       0, memoryStream.Length);
```

This would avoid creating a copy of the data.

You seem to be concerned about memory usage - do you have any reason for this? Have you performed profiling and found that garbage collection is a bottleneck? If not, don't worry about it until you *do* find it to be a problem. It usually isn't.

Comment: So you wouldn't wrap the memoryStream in a using as the decorator does that for you?

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: I prefer code to be correct and robust. It's easy to put this in a separate method, and then it can work on any stream, without you having to worry about whether it's okay not to dispose of the stream or not. As for disposal - disposing of the `StreamReader` disposes of the underlying stream for you. Having said which, I'd normally have a using statement around the code *creating* the stream in the first place. You haven't shown that.

Comment: more code more problems. Whats not robust about the above (there are some checks before the outgoing return)?

Comment: Not had any issues on memory at all, just trying to reduce the "look" of the code base. Make everything as terse as possible without affecting performance. I know that the underlying CLR will look after us, as long as we are not too stupid, although the double string thing was overlooked by myself, not too of-fay with the Encoder class.

Comment: jon why you use the buffer version, I found this, whats the difference?

Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: Calling `ToArray()` will copy the data. `GetBuffer` doesn't. However, I would strongly advise against making everything "as terse as possible". Sometimes that's the right way to go, sometimes it's not. Concentrate on making it as *readable* as possible, while still being correct.

Answer (score 1):

> "Hopefully getting the Garbage Collector to kick in soon as."

I'm going to give a short and over-simplified GC primer, because you don't seem to appreciate how it works...

First off, the **GC isn't deterministic**.  It doesn't kick in "soon as"; it generally kicks in when there's memory pressure.  So regardless of what you do in your method, you can't guarantee that it'll run at the end of your method, or at any other specific time.  Typically, a GC will run when there's not enough space in GC Generation 0 to allocate a new object.

Secondly, if you don't call `Dispose` on your `MemoryStream` (either manually or with a `using` block) your **GC won't release that memory**, even if it runs.  When you call a typical `Dispose`, two things happen: first, the object is tidied up, and second a call is made to `GC.SuppressFinalize`.  The latter call is important: it tells the GC that you've already done cleanup for the object.

If haven't called `Dispose` on your object, then the GC will put your object on a "Finalizer queue."  This is a queue of objects waiting to be tidied up.  If your object ends up on this queue, it *can't be released*, because the queue is keeping it alive.  That means your object gets pushed into GC generation 1 and won't get cleared up for a *lot* longer.  GC generation 1 won't get collected until generation 0 has been collected and the objects that can't be released don't fit in Gen 1.  For most apps the ratio is approximately 10 GC gen-0 collects for one GC gen-1 collect, so you're prolonging the life of your object by a factor of 10 by not calling `Dispose`.

Moral of the story: if a type implements `IDisposable`, and you're worried about memory use (or even just about good programming practise), **call the `Dispose` method**.  It's there for a reason.

Thirdly: Even if you call `Dispose` sensibly, the **memory release still isn't deterministic**, because all you do ensure that the *next* GC will release the memory.

Finally: **Don't be tempted to call `GC.Collect` yourself.**  This is almost always a bad thing, and will typically result in your application having a *higher* memory footprint, not a lower one.

Comment: To extend my answer a little and quote your post back at you: you said "not create references that are not required."  By *not* calling `Dispose`, you force the GC to keep an extra reference to your object on the Finalizer queue.

Comment: Your talking about Heap space, with modern Pc's the heap should be ok and I trust the GC more than myself to free up objects. I was referring to stack space. You make a lot of assumptions about me. As I said, Hopefully. Calling IDispose on a MemoryStream won't realistically make a difference apart from setting some flags.

Comment: You been reading "CLR via C#" by Jeffrey Richter by any chance ;)

Comment: Actually no, but it's always been on my list :-)

Comment: I'm afraid to say that there are some incorrectness in your text. The presence of the Dispose() function does not affect how the GC works, it's the presence of the Finalizer that does that. Failure to call Dispose does not result in the GC won't release the memory. The memory will be released when the GC run (but if there is a Finalizer, it may not be released until after the second garbage collection, if you didn't call SuppressFinalize). The Dispose() and Finalizer is not used to release memory, but unmanaged resources, such as file locks, TCP sockets, etc.

Comment: Anyway... you didn't mention anything about Heap vs Stack in your question, so if that's what you're worried about you should perhaps restate.  The real answer to your stated question "why shouldn't I allow one of my developers to do this?" is: because it's rubbish coding practise and should be jumped up and down on, violently, with spiky boots.

Comment: I can't do anything to invoke the GC to do my bidding. It does it in its own sweet time. The way I like it. no matter how much understanding you think you got on the GC, it will still do what it likes.

Comment: I'm not "preaching"; I thought I was answering your question.  If you don't call Dispose then you change what the GC can do with your object and you'll use (heap) memory for longer as a result.  If you don't care about that then that's up to you - but it's likely to be more memory that you seem to be worrying about leaving on the stack!

Comment: @Pete (Scooby comic expression). Huh Huh? Whats that got to do with the Using statement, that depends on the IDisposable?

Comment: He's pointing out that my case is only true where a finalizer exists on the class.  As far as I know, though, the base `Object` class has a finalizer, so this is always the case: the option is whether or not you override it.

Comment: In the case of MemoryStream you don't get any extra beans by calling Using, unless you can correct me on this. I agree that it is a "best practice" because of it implementation pattern, but there is very little you can do about speeding up Heap collection. In this case it doesn't improve your chances one Iota.

Comment: One last time: if you don't call dispose on the `MemoryStream` then `GC.SuppressFinalize` doesn't get called, and then the GC will promote your object to Gen 1 instead of collecting it.  So, your heap memory won't be reclaimed during the first GC.  I really can't explain it any more clearly, so if you still think I'm wrong then I can do nothing to change that!

Comment: Where is the GC.suppressFinalize line of code with regard to MemoryStream?

Comment: From Reflector, your call to `MemoryStream.Dispose()` will call the inherited method from the base `Stream` class.  That calls `Stream.Close()` which calls `this.Dispose(true)` and then `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`.

Comment: Freachable Queue - CLR via C# Jeffrey Richter. Got my head into time bending mode, and read it a couple of times to make sure I knew what I was talking about. Object has no reference, goes to this queue for finalization it gets called AUTOMATICALLY.

Comment: This doesn't contradict anything I've said... it's exactly what I was referring to.  If you don't call `Dispose`, being on the Freachable queue causes your object not to be GCed until the next generation.  If you've already called `Dispose` (and thus `GC.SuppressFinalize`) then your object doesn't get put on the Freachable queue at all and is GCed immediately.

Comment: You have no control of the Freachable Queue. Call IDispose till your blue in the face, will make no difference to what the GC will do with the Finalize methods :). The lack of reference to the object is the key to finalization. The Object will not get promoted as you incorrectly state as it no longer has a reference.

Comment: *sigh* I actually give up.  You've misquoted me (I didn't suggest I had control of the freachable queue) enough times that I'm convinced you won't understand what I'm saying no matter how many times I try!

Comment: Actually... because I really do think it's important that people understand this stuff properly... would you like 100 lines of code that *proves* that your finalizer won't get called if you call Dispose first?  We are so far off your original question here that's it's completely irrelevant, but if you're interested it's a very simple test to write.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers - uh - what I said has nothing to do with the using statement.

Comment: @Dan, Been to  Tesco's done a bit of shopping, came back did more reading. I hate to say it. You were right all along. :)

Comment: @Dan I think that for most of this discussion we were talking at cross purposes, I was looking in the wrong places for the answers, when I came to the sections (Book) that discussed this I found that your description of what was happening was more fitting and correct.

Comment: @Dan @Pete, been a pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

The MemoryStream implements IDisposable because it inherits from the more general Stream class. But there is really no need to call Dispose() on this.

The point with the Dispose() function is to tell the class to clean up any unmanaged resources that it might have acquired. For a FileStream that would be file handles and file locks. But the MemoryStream only allocates memory, and therefore it is not necessary to dispose it. When your memory stream is out of scope, it is ready for garbage collection, no matter if you call Dispose() or not.

But normally, you should always call Dispose() on objects that implements IDisposable, and allowing exceptions may create confusion among developers who do not have a thorough understanding of what is going on.

I think some of your concerns come from a poor understanding of the .NET memory and garbage collection model. I learned from the book [Applied Microsoft .NET Framework Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735614229). It is an ancient book, targeting .NET 1.0, but the section on memory management and garbage collection is really worth the read.

Comment: I perfectly understand the garbage collector. But I always think that scoping is relevant no matter what the Garbage Collector may or may not do with my lovely heap space. I trust it. If you know that something is going out of scope, you can bet your bottom dollar that the reference will disappear. If something is not referenced, then I would hope that somewhere along the line, the GC will say, "yup not being referenced" and do something about it WHEN IT DECIDES. The relationship should be one of trust. And yes I do always dispose of objects that NEED disposing that use UNMANAGED resources.

Comment: When you say, 'I would hope that somewhere along the line, the GC will say, "yup not being referenced" and do something about it WHEN IT DECIDES', you are mostly correct. The GC does not say "not being referenced" (unless the object has a finalizer). The object is just no longer on the list of referenced objects, and when the GC repacks the current objects, your non-referenced object will probably be overwritten. Only if your object has a finalizer, will the GC actually do anything active with the object, namely call the finalizer.

Comment: Hmmm - by just reading your comments on the other answer I can see that you already have a good understanding of what's going on ;) (F-reachable queues, and such). I just don't understand what it is that you are worried about then ;)

Comment: Cross purpose conversation. I just think that the code was wrong (in the question). I think my gut feeling is to continue using the USING statement wrapped around the memoryStream. It feels better.